# OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server returned message "ORA-00904: invalid identifier

Tags: sql, oracle

After one week of R&D am still not able to findout why getting below error while executing below query.
Plz help ..
Am running below query in Sql and my linked db is in oracle

```
select * from openquery(oracle,'select vUINno from sd_erf.employee_view')
```

> OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server  returned message "ORA-00904: invalid identifier

Comment: Presumably, it does not recognize `vUINno` in the view.

Comment: but this filed is there in the view

Comment: _"but this filed is there in the view"_   filed?   The code is referenceing a column and view name. What the contents may mean to the business ("filed") is irrelevant.  That said, you insist it exists, but oracle disagrees, and my money is on oracle.  So prove it exists. Update your question to add the formatted text output of 'desc sd_erf.employee_view', as executed when connected to the oracle database with sqlplus.

Comment: Apologies - I saw "filed" and thought you meant "file id", when I guess you meant "field". (in databases they are properly called "column", not "field").  In any event, the diagnostic remains the same.  We need to see the actual definition of ' sd_erf.employee_view', as actually reported by oracle.  We might be dealing with a case-sensitiviry issue.  Oracle and MSSQL treat them differently.